# RSYNCWRAPPER: rsync exited with code 12

Tags: node.js, rsync

I'm using [rsyncwrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsyncwrapper) node module.

Here is my code:

```
rsync({
    src: source_path,
    dest: dest,
    ssh: true,
    recursive: true,
    privateKey: keystring,
    port: port,
    args: ['--perms','--rsync-path="mkdir -p '+dest_path+' && rsync"']
},function (error,stdout,stderr,cmd) {
    if ( error ) {
        // failed
        var data_response = {
            'Status': 'Failed',
            'Message': 'Rsync Failed=>'+error+stdout+stderr+cmd
        };

        logger.info("[Rsync] Response=>" + JSON.stringify(data_response));
        console.log(error.message);
        res.json(data_response);

    } else {
        console.log("Success");
        var data_response = {
            'Status': 'Success',
            'Message': 'Rsync Success'
        };

        logger.info("[Rsync] Response=>" + JSON.stringify(data_response));
        res.json(data_response);
    }
});
```

However I get this error:

```
[2018-08-07 13:15:33.491] [INFO] JDWF-API - [Rsync] Response=>{"Status":"Failed","Message":"Rsync Failed=>Error: rsync exited with code 12WARNING : Unauthorized access to this system is forbidden and will be\nprosecuted by law. By accessing this system, you agree that your actions\nmay be monitored if unauthorized usage is suspected.\nmkdir: cannot create directory `/DATA/userWorkpace/devteam/7000003': Permission denied\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]\nrsync /DATA/files/gs/7000003/input// wf-sync@192.168.1.23:/DATA/userWorkpace/devteam/7000003/input// --rsh \"ssh -p 47365 -i /DATA/jdwf-api/secure/wf-sync.dat\" --recursive --perms --rsync-path=\"mkdir -p /DATA/userWorkpace/devteam/7000003/input// && rsync\""}
rsync exited with code 12
```

I have given 777 permissions to the folder. It doesnt fix it. Can someone help me out please.